# Google Test C Function With Wait Loop

Tags: c, unit-testing, googletest

I'm crafting unit-tests for an embedded C application (**NOTE**: C, not C++).  This very low-end 8-bit application does not use threading or an RTOS.  Instead, I've gone old-school with a round-robin task dispatcher.

I'm using Google Test because that's what's readily available here.  It's been working for the vast majority of my cases, but I've come across one corner case.

I have this function here:

```
bool UartPutsWithWait(char *str)
{
    while (sUartData.m_flags.m_TxBusy)
    {
        /* Wait for previous transmission to complete */
    }
    return UartPuts(str);
}   /* UartPutsWithWait */
```

The "TxBusy" flag is set within an interrupt routine on the target.
"UartPuts" has undergone unit testing successfully.

My question is: *Does anybody have a useful way of setting up Google Test (or Google Mock) to set the "TxBusy" flag after one or two iterations?*

My target is VERY memory-constrained (8KB of Flash for the high-end products), so re-implementing with threads and/or tasks is unlikely to be a useful answer.

If all else fails, I'll have to wear the risk of not unit-testing that particular line of code as thoroughly as I'd like.

I note also that my task dispatcher loop in my main() function is going to have to be tweaked to allow use of Google Mock.  That, I can live with.

Comment: There's a tip for an answer here: http://vandervoord.net/blog/2015/5/19/unit-test-how-infinite-loops  .

Answer (score 0):

There's a tip for an answer here: http://vandervoord.net/blog/2015/5/19/unit-test-how-infinite-loops

Basically, I've included the following in a header file:

```
/** Definition for waiting macro to allow better unit-testing */
#ifdef  GOOGLE_TEST
#define WAIT_FOR_TEST   (googleTestCount-- != 0)
#else   /* !GOOGLE_TEST */
#define WAIT_FOR_TEST   (true)
#endif  /* !GOOGLE_TEST */
```

I've then modified the function as follows:

```
bool UartPutsWithWait(char *str)
{
    while ((sUartData.m_flags.m_TxBusy) && (WAIT_FOR_TEST))
    {
        /* Wait for previous transmission to complete */
    }
    return UartPuts(str);
}   /* UartPutsWithWait */
```

A quick compile before and after the modification shows that my compiler correctly optimises out the non-test case. I just need to declare the "googleTestCount" variable before including the code.

I should add that I'm testing the C modules by creating a C++ unit test file and then #including the C file inside it as follows:

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "types.h"
#include "TestRegisters.h"

namespace uart
{
extern "C"
{
#include "uart.c"
}
```

"types.h" defines those types not available in the standard C++ build, while "TestRegisters.h" includes a few classes for defining register behaviour and the declarations of the registers I'm using.  This enables me to unit-test the hardware layers without needing the hardware in the loop.

Of course, a lot more work would be required for me to model the behaviour accurately.

Answer (score 0):

Further refinement has happened in the half-hour or so since I posted the previous answer.

In the unit-test file, I've defined the following variables:

```
int googleTestCount = 0;
bool googleTestFlag = false;
```

I've then added the following slight variation to the WAIT_FOR_TEST macro defined above:

```
/** Definition for wait for busy macro to allow better unit-testing */
#ifdef  GOOGLE_TEST
#define WAIT_FOR_BUSY_TEST   ((googleTestCount-- == 0) ? (sUartData.m_flags.m_TxBusy = googleTestFlag, false) : true)
#else   /* !GOOGLE_TEST */
#define WAIT_FOR_BUSY_TEST   (true)
#endif  /* !GOOGLE_TEST */
```

This definition allows me to wait as long as I like and then either leave the flag set as the loop exits or have it clear.

I've also reused the WAIT_FOR_TEST macro for the "FOREVER" function in the main loop, allowing me to run the main loop as many times as I please as well.